# Retorno de dados ajax com php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estou criando uma modal em ajax onde ele vai retornar o id e lista as informações na modal o problema é que o php retorna a "página inteira" para o ajax e não me dá nenhum erro no console, já tentei utilizar o firebug

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".j_modal").click(function() {
            var id_email = $(this).attr('id');          

            $.ajax({
                url:    'Cad_emails',
                type:   'POST',
                data:   "acao=abre_modal&id_email="+id_email,
                success:    function(dados){
                    console.log(dados);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<?php 
if ($_POST['acao']) {
    $j_idemail = $_POST['id_email'];

    $resultado = $this->db->get_where('emails', array('i_email' => $j_idemail))->result_array();

    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

segue o print do consolo onde ele retorna o HTML da página quando deveria retornar um array com os dados passador no ajax
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*estou utilizando codeigniter*

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cad_emails extends CI_Controller {

public $data_up = '';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('emails_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('text', 'anexos_helper'));
    $last_email = $this->db->query("SELECT emails.i_email, emails.`status` FROM `emails` ORDER BY emails.i_email DESC LIMIT 1")->result_array();

    $regras = array(
        array(
            'field' =>  'assunto',
            'label' =>  'Assunto',
            'rules' =>  'trim|required|max_length[100]|min_length[4]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' =>  'corpo',
            'label' =>  'Mensagem',
            'rules' =>  'trim|required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' =>  'status',
            'label' =>  'Status',
            'rules' =>  'required'
        )
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($regras);

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $last_idmail = $last_email[0]['i_email']+1;

        $inputs = array(
            'i_email'   =>  $last_idmail,
            'dt_email'  =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),//2015-05-27 16:43:13
            'assunto'   =>  $this->input->post('assunto'),
            'corpo'     =>  htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('corpo')),
            'status'    =>  $this->input->post('status')
        );

        $anexos = upload_anexo('anexos', $last_idmail);

        if ($anexos['file_name'] != ''){
            $data_up = array(
                'i_email'   =>  $last_idmail,
                'legenda'   =>  NULL,
                'arquivo'   =>  $anexos['file_name'],
                'status'    =>  'A'
            );

            $this->db->insert('anexos', $data_up);
        }


        $this->db->insert('emails', $inputs);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('ok', 'E-mail cadastrado com sucesso!');
        redirect(current_url());

    }
    $data['for_emails'] = $this->emails_model->get_emails();
    $data['for_envios'] = $this->emails_model->get_envios();
    $this->load->view('cad_emails/emails_plincipal', $data);
}

}

/* End of file Cad_emails.php */
/* Location: .//C/wamp/www/emails_crebas/app/controllers/Cad_emails.php */
```

Segue o conteúdo do controlador mais creio que o problema não esteja nele, pois ele não tem nenhuma interação com o ajax que etá apenas na view.

Comment: Pode colocar o html do form tbm?

Comment: `Cad_emails` possui o que?

Comment: @rray não estou utilizando form apenas um botão com a class `j_modal`

Comment: @MaiconCarraro `Cad_emails` é o controlador principal, não possui nada associado a dúvida apenas um cadastro de um formulário, mais caso seja necessário posto o conteúdo

Comment: Provavelmente está retornando a página inteira, pois no controller do CI que você está usando você não está retornando uma view somente com o conteúdo necessário. Você pode alterar o seu controller para retornar um JSON e trabalhar com o JSON no javascript também.

Comment: Postei o conteúdo do controlador para vocês darem uma olhada

Comment: Onde você está retornando o ID e lista?

Comment: o script que recebe os dados via POST está na mesma página que submete a requisição? Eu falo isso devido ao código que postou.. Se estiver dessa forma é óbvio que sempre vai dar erro...  O trecho if ($_POST['acao']) { deveria também bloquear os outros códigos.. Mesmo assim não é uma boa prática.

Comment: Acho q a view q tu tá retornando deve tbm está retornando o layout do sistema.. Não sei no codeigniter, mas no cakephp podemos dizer **$this->layout = false;** e exibir apenas a view.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente os web frameworks carregam o template do site por default. Sendo assim, para retornar um json você precisa checar a documentação referente a versão de framework do seu projeto, e adicionar uma regra na classe que renderiza o site para ignorar o template.

Acredito que [esse link](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_content_type) possa te ajudar.

Perceba que o proprio framework já esta preparado para lidar com esse tipo de dado: (O codigo abaixo foi retirado da propria doc do codeignite)

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));

//$this seria o escopo do seu controller
```

Há tambem a possibilidade de forçar o encerramento da execução do PHP, porém esse metodo não é tão bonito quanto o anterior.

```
die(json_encode($meusDados));
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo o `CodeIgniter` e as vezes preciso também de pegar algumas informações via ajax. O que recomendo você a fazer é criar um `controller` especial só para requisições ajax. Eu faria um controller chamado **ajax.php** :

```
<?php
class Ajax extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function cad_emails(){
     //TODO CONTEÚDO DO CAD_EMAILS
    }
}
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".j_modal").click(function() {
            var id_email = $(this).attr('id');          

            $.ajax({
                url:    '<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/cad_emails',
                type:   'POST',
                data:   {acao: "abre_modal", id_email: id_email},
                success:    function(dados){
                    console.log(dados);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<?php 
if ($_POST['acao']) {
    $j_idemail = $_POST['id_email'];

    $resultado = $this->db->get_where('emails', array('i_email' => $j_idemail))->result_array();

    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

Coloque todo o código na função `cad_emails()` do controller **ajax**. Mas sempre lembre-se de não colocar por exemplo o **$this->load->view()** ou algo que carrega templates, caso contrário, ele também enviará via ajax todo o conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
class Ajax extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function cad_emails(){
     //TODO CONTEÚDO DO CAD_EMAILS
    }
}
?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".j_modal").click(function() {
            var id_email = $(this).attr('id');          

            $.ajax({
                url:    '<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/cad_emails',
                type:   'POST',
                data:   {acao: "abre_modal", id_email: id_email},
                success:    function(dados){
                    console.log(dados);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<?php 
if ($_POST['acao']) {
    $j_idemail = $_POST['id_email'];

    $resultado = $this->db->get_where('emails', array('i_email' => $j_idemail))->result_array();

    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```